# Is it possible to submit 2 versions for the same app for 2 different regions/countries

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I'm building an IOS app, but figured out later that my app should act totally differently based on the region/country. Basically, I only want to support 3 countries, but every country has its own rules and data. It makes no sense in my case to add all the logic, media, etc., in a single app.

Is it possible to do something like you can do on Google's PlayStore, submit a different app for each country all under the same name?

I tried to search for this issue but couldn't find any helpful resource.

Comment: I suggest you direct this question directly to Apple.  I don't believe that different regions have different iOS App Stores.  This seems like a horrible idea since it would be very hard to support and update the same code base across multiple projects.  Seems it would be much easier to adress the localization issues in a different way.

Comment: **yes**, it is possible, of course. we have many same applications for different markets like one for the UK market, one for the US market, etc... and they have different contents only which are specified for the current country, the application's core, name, icon and purpose are the exact same for every country.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for your answer, I believe it depends on the case, in my case it would be easier to submit 3 different apps for 3 different countries because otherwise I have to put alot of effort to support 3 different countries in 1 codebase.

Comment: @holex Thank you, one question, do you submit the 3 different apps in the same time to the app store, or you have to submit 1 by 1 ? as i know if you are publishing to play store, you can upload a different app for any different region or country. so basically you publish 1 app but the downloaded code will be based on the user's country. is it the same way in app store or it's different ?

Comment: @ra_htial, out practice we are focusing on one market as same time only, so the technically we can publish the different applications one-by-one 4-5 days delay between them.

Comment: @holex may you please add your comments as an answer so I mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @ra_htial, I've added my comments as answer.

Comment: App store connect does not allow to create new app with same name. How did you do that? I am looking for a solution to distribute my apps for different servers based on countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes**, it is possible, of course. we have many same applications for different markets like one for the UK market, one for the US market, etc... and they have different contents only which are specified for the current country, the application's core, name, icon and purpose are the exact same for every country.

our practice, we are focusing on one market at same time only, so technically we publish the different applications one-by-one 4-5 days delay between them.

Comment: can you please tell me what are the steps for upload app for different - 2 countries. I am looking around it but not getting any proper help. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @holex: Could you please tell how to upload single app for different countries in App store? It will be great if you can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Anand, you can customised the territories in iTunes Connect portal, under _Priceing and Acvailability_ and _Availabilty_ section. the default is all countries, but there you can disable/enable the the countries one-by-one for your app.

Comment: I am trying to differentiate app versions for specific countries like for united states different data center and for the europe different data center. I need to keep exactly same app except data center. I have tried to create different app with same name but app store connect does not allow to do that and says you already have sama name with another app. How did you create same app for different countries? I have also tried to create app different app and change to availability  each of them and after that try to change the name to original one but it still give me same error

Comment: if the bundle is different in any way (eg. configuration, URLs, code), you'd need to submit two different apps with two different bundle IDs; if you can afford to implement to determine the desired data-center in runtime (eg. via fetching info from back-end based on location or IP or client or any internal information which could be used) then you can do it with one bundle – these are really your options here.

Comment: So if the bundle id is different. Then it is basically having two apps. Are you saying create 2 different apps?

Comment: @RohitSingh, yes, there will be two apps in AppStore in this case.

Comment: The question was if it is possible to have two versions of the same app. Your answer starts with yes it is possible. But then you explain how to have 2 different apps. Little confusing.

Comment: @RohitSingh, what do you mean by _two versions_ then? same bundle id, but version `1.0` and version `2.0` would be simultaneously available for the end-users, so they can choose which version they wanna download?

Answer (score 6):

You *can* submit different apps for different countries, but I would advise against it. Apple also says you should avoid doing this.

What happens if someone installs your app, then moves to a different country? What happens to people that travel a lot? Will they be able to switch to the correct country/language? What happens when you expand your app to support 20+ languages? You should really consider having one app to support all regions.

If you have large amounts of data, you could let the user choose which dataset/language to download. This may complicate your implementation but offers the best experience for users.

We have a project here with 32 different languages. As separate apps. You may not need this many, but think of all the tedium of creating different Xcode targets, building, updating iTunes Connect information, managing bug reports for different versions, etc. It can cause a lot of overhead.

If you insist on making separate apps you can do so, there is nothing preventing this. You just need to create an app for each region you are targeting and submit it separately to the app store. You can use iTunes Connect to manage which markets each app is available in.

Comment: there are some very useful way to work with only one source code, so you don't need to separate the application to 32 different ones at all. the `Xcode` has full support to do it properly but, of course, you have to publish every target one-by-one, however you need to do the changes only once, so the maintenance won't be 32 times complicated, if you build up the project well.

Comment: I have this senario that if someone travel from 1 country to another, but basically my app logic is that if he downloaded a country version he will stick with this country. and as i said before it's only 3 countries i'm not gonna support more than that. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score -2):

you can use if else in your app to behave differently for 3 different countries

Comment: ya i know, but including alot of media and images that will not be used it's not a good idea too right ?