# rollout different release on different countries

Tags: android, ios, app-store-connect

I want to rollouts different releases on different countries

Currently, my release version in 4.0.2 and is available of UK, USA, Canada
Now I want to make a new release version in 4.0.3 and this will be only available for USA.
The rest of the countries UK and Canada will have version 4.0.2

Is this possible is Apple App and Google Play store? and how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be possible. You can upload multiple apps for multiple regions. Better to address the root issue. Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970979/is-it-possible-to-submit-2-versions-for-the-same-app-for-2-different-regions-cou)