# How does Uber localize App previews screenshots in AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, app-store

I have an app that is available in US Appstore. I want to release my App to India AppStore. But the problem is that the screenshots have US currency on some of the screenshots. So I want the localized screenshots for Indian users (Rupees on the screenshots).

I know it is possible to localize the screenshots based on language preferences in AppStore but not based on the country.

How does Uber is localizing the screenshots ?

**This is what I see Uber in US AppStore**
[image]

**This is what I see Uber in India AppStore**

[image]

I have reached out to Apple support team they say it is not possible to localize images based on AppStore country. Then how is Uber doing that?

Comment: Maybe Uber is an exception in the store but I believe most just release multiple apps in the App Store and manage them per region. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030420/526828